# How to get Dell G3223Q monitor to support good looking, clear, sharp text at non-native resolutions on Mac

Tags: macos, resolution, external-display, 4k-resolution

**I would like to figure out how to get my G3223Q monitor to support good looking, clear, sharp text at non-native resolutions on Mac.**

#### Behavior I am looking for

When I say "support non-native resolutions" I mean the behavior of the S2817Q. I used a friend's Dell monitor (S2817Q) that nominally had 4k maximum resolution (3840x2160) but also looked really good, with extremely sharp text, at a scaled 3k resolution (3008x1692) and 2560x1440. When set to 3008x1692, I used my mac's System Report to figure out what dimensions my Mac thought the monitor was, and it said "Resolution: 6016x3384; UI Looks like: 3008x1692." **So, the monitor was behaving like a 6k monitor as far as my computer could tell, even though the monitor's specification says its max resolution is 3840 x 2160!!!** That is the magical support for non-native resolutions that I am looking for. Similarly, when I selected 2560x1440 resolution, the System Report said "Resolution: 5120x2880; UI Looks like: 2560x1440." Furthermore, in the menu for System Preferences --> Displays, the resolution options appear as "Larger Text ... Default ... More space," with a little thumbnail for each option, just like the resolution options for my Macbook's built-in display.

#### Behavior I have found

In contrast, I purchased a new 4k Dell monitor (G3223Q) that doesn't seem to support non-native resolutions. The resolution options appeared as a list rather than thumbnails. I don't really care about the UI of the resolution options, but when they appear as thumbnails, I think it signals some special kind of interoperability between the monitor and my MacBook. The monitor's spec said its maximum dimensions are 3840x1692. The scaled options did not include my preferred 3008x1692 but did include 2560x1440. When set to 2560x1440, the System Report said "Resolution: 2560x1440; UI Looks like: 2560x1440." So no special magic happening there. It looks fine, but not extra clear and sharp.

#### What I need help with

I want to configure my G3223Q monitor to have behavior similar to the S2817Q. I have tried searching for how to do it, but I just don't have the technical words to describe "looks really clear and sharp supporting non-native resolutions that are not even a whole number multiple of its specified dimensions." Does the monitor hardware have more physical pixels than its specified maximum resolution of 3840x1692? Does the monitor software have special support for in-between resolutions? Does the macOS software perform the scaling in a special way? Is my G3223Q monitor even capable of the same behavior as the S2817Q?

**Please help me to figure out the technical language that describes the behavior of the S2817Q with respect to non-native resolutions, so I can configure my G3223Q monitor better.**

#### System

My system:
Macbook Air M2, 2022, macOS Ventura 13.0

Friend's system (used for some of the screenshots below, seems to have the same behavior as mine):
Macbook Pro M1, 2020, macOS Big Sur 11.6

#### Usage

I typically use my computer for office work, and I have an appreciation for extra sharp text. (G3223Q happens to be a gaming monior, but I don't really use it for gaming.)

#### Links

S2817Q -- [detail page](https://www.dell.com/ae/business/p/dell-s2817q-monitor/pd) -- [manual](https://dl.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_display_projector/esuprt_display/dell-s2817q-monitor_user%27s%20guide_en-us.pdf)
G3223Q -- [detail page](https://www.dell.com/en-us/shop/dell-32-4k-uhd-gaming-monitor-g3223q/apd/210-bdbk/monitors-monitor-accessories) -- [manual](https://dl.dell.com/content/manual74300550-dell-g3223q-monitor-user-s-guide.pdf?language=en-us)

#### Images

**System report showing double resolution pixel magic on the S2817Q where the monitor behaves as though it had twice the dimensions of the resolution setting, and more pixels that the monitor's spec says it has.** (This screenshot is from my friend's macbook, which seems to have the same behavior as mine. I would have provided a screenshot from my own system, but we live in different cities and the monitor is with him.)
[image]

**System report showing G3223Q with resolution the same as appearance.**
[image]

**Example of thumbnail UI for choosing resolution of built in display and S2817Q**
[image]

**Example of list UI for choosing resolution of G3223Q**
[image]

Comment: You might get more/better answers if you get your questions moved to AskDifferent https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions.

Answer (score 2):

This is not really an answer, but is a bit long as just a comment.

Your S2817Q is working at its best. macOS is detecting it as a hiDPI monitor. When you ask for "looks like" 2560x1440, macOS builds the screen image in a virtual screen which is twice that size - i.e. 5120x2880. macOS then does the downscaling to the true 4K size of the screen.

The G3223Q is only being detected as a loDPI screen and the internal screen buffer is 2560x1440. And that is being sent to the display. I would expect text to look fuzzy or blocky. Comparing your screenshots, the G3223Q does look a bit fuzzy.

So the G3223Q is not being used at the full potential of its 4K resolution.

I don't know why, but some suggestions:

1. Try a different cable - preferably the one from the S2817Q which you know supports 4K resolution.
2. After that you can try swapping between the two Macs.
3. G3223Q is a gaming monitor (144HZ). I would not expect that to work at higher than 60HZ with a Mac. So try setting the monitor to 60Hz.

I don't think there is anything inherently bad about using that monitor with a Mac. It should be possible to get it working better. I hope that someone using a G3223Q with a Mac can assist.

Edit: Here is a discussion about issues with G3223Q. https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/i-think-my-macbook-pro-m1-max-is-forcing-ycbcr-for-external-dell-4k-monitor.2390040/ It also suggests that more than 60HZ is possible.