# How does my monitor have more pixels than its specification

Tags: macos, resolution, external-display, pixels

I plugged my laptop (2020 M1 macbook pro running macos 11.6 Big Sur) into a Dell [S2817Q](https://www.dell.com/ae/business/p/dell-s2817q-monitor/pd) monitor, whose specification says its maximum dimensions are 3820 x 2160. In System Preferences, I configured the monitor to display a scaled resolution of 2560 x 1440. However, in the system report, it says

```
Resolution: 5120 x 2880 (5K/UHD+ - Ultra High Definition Plus)
UI Looks like: 2560 x 1440 @ 30.00Hz
```

This monitor cannot be configured to a resolution of 5120 x 2880.

How is it that the monitor tricks the computer into thinking it has more pixels than it actually has? Is it in the hardware or the laptop's software, or the monitor's software? What is the name for this technology and how does it work? Which other monitors do this?

[image: Screenshot from System Report emphasizing the monitor resolution described in this post.]

Comment: It sounds like it has a decent scaler  (i.e., a chip that automatically resizes video on the fly) and it's advertising (to the host GPU, via EDID over HDMI or DP or whatever) all the resolutions its scaler can handle well. I don't know how someone might find products that do that, since even the docs on your display that does it, don't mention it.

Answer (score 3):

You have asked for "looks like" 2560x1440 which is very different to that of the physical screen 3820x2160.

When the two sizes are different with non-integer scaling (2160/1440 is not an integer), macOS internally uses a virtual screen which is twice the "looks like" size you have asked for - that is 5120x2880. macOS and all apps then put objects (windows, buttons, fonts, etc.) on this virtual screen.

The final step is that macOS scales this large virtual screen from 5120x2880 onto the physical 3820x2160 screen.

This put all the control about scaling into the hands of macOS and makes for uniform looking scaling with the best possible look. Also apps do not need to be concerned about the details of scaling.

So what you are seeing is normal. The monitor has not tricked the computer. The control is entirely in macOS with physical scaling being the final step.

I do agree that the "Resolution: 5120 x 2880 (5K/UHD+ - Ultra High Definition Plus)" is confusing. This is the large virtual screen and not the physical resolution of the monitor.

Comment: I don't think this is quite correct. I don't think macOS ever offers a higher res virtual screen than what the display advertises as its native resolution via EDID signaling over DP or HDMI. So if the native resolution is 3840x2160, macOS will offer to treat it as 1920x1080 @2x (i.e. pixel doubled / retina), but not the other way around.

Comment: @Spiff Certainly it will offer 1920x1080 which as you say has a scaling factor of 2.  But the OP was offered and chose 2560x1440. This is less than the physical resolution of the screen and has a non-integer scale factor (2160/1440). Internally a virtual display of twice that (5128x2880) is used by macOS and apps. This whole display is then reduced to the physical dimensions of the screen and sent to the screen.

Comment: I understand your hypothesis. My alternative hypothesis is that the Dell display is offering (via EDID) virtual resolutions bigger than native resolution, and the Dell display is doing the downscaling. I've never seen a Mac offer to do what you're claiming the Mac offered. In fact, in OP's previous post, he asked why a slightly different model of Dell display was not triggering the same behavior from his Mac. That, combined with never seeing a Mac offer to do what you're claiming, is why I think your hypothesis is at the very least insufficient to explain the observed behavior.

Comment: I wasn't offering an hypothesis.

Comment: Please see [OP's previous Question](https://superuser.com/questions/1798693/finding-a-monitor-that-supports-non-native-resolution-for-mac) for context. If, as you assert, it's his Mac and not his Dell display that's offering the over-res virtual display and doing the downscaling, then why doesn't his Mac do the same thing for his G3223Q? Or can you point to any Apple documentation or reliable third party sources or other evidence that it's the Mac and not the display that's doing this?

Comment: @Spiff if you think my answer is wrong, I suggest you make your own answer.